# Can't add new rows to SQL table using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a code that will read in multiple delimited txt files, and will go through them and parse the data and then is supposed to add them to rows in my SQL table. The problem I am having is that it will read in all of the files and parse them (I know it is doing it because currently I also have it writing to console and it is writing all of the values I need. It is then supposed to move the files to another folder when it is done, which it is also doing because after it runs the files are only in the separate folder. The issue I am having is that my code will only add one row to the SQL table. If all of the rows are empty, I can run the code with a file and it will make the row and add the numbers. However, if I run it again, the code will parse the data but will not make a new row for the numbers. Therefore, when I try to do it with multiple files, it only adds the first one and then will continue running and parsing the rest, but will not add them to the table

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace prototype_using_filehelpers
{

    class ManagerReport
    {

        [DelimitedRecord("|")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
        [IgnoreFirst()]
        [IgnoreLast(2)]


        public class ManagerReportNames
        {


            public int? MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
            public int? MASTER_VALUE;
            public string RESORT;
            public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
            public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
            public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
            public string SUB_GRP_1;
            public string DESCRIPTION;
            public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
            public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
            public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
            public int? HEADING_1;
            [FieldOptional]
            public string HEADING_2;
            [FieldOptional]
            [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
            public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
            [FieldOptional]
            public decimal? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;


        }

        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string originalPath, string destinationPath)
        {


            // first check if path exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(originalPath))
                // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
                return;
            var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(originalPath);
            // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
            var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            // loops through directory looking for txt files
            for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the file
                var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];
                //sets lines to the files full extention so it can then be called at a later time
                string lines = csvFile.FullName;

                // read the csv file line by line
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
                var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ManagerReportNames[];


                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);

                    string Heading = record.HEADING_2;
                    string Group = record.SUB_GRP_1;
                    string Description = record.DESCRIPTION;
                    string column;
                    decimal? amount;

                    if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM")
                    {
                        column = "ADR";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "ADR_minus_Comp_and_House";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOMREV_AVL_ROOMS_MINUS_OOO")
                    {
                        column = "Revenue_per_Available_Room_minus_OOO";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "TOTAL_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Revenue";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOM_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Room_Revenue";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "FOOD_BEV_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Food_And_Beverage_Revenue";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OTHER_REVENUE" && Description == "Other Revenue")
                    {
                        column = "Other_Revenue";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "PHYSICAL_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Rooms_in_Hotel";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_MINUS_COMP_HU")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House_Use";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "COMP_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Complimentary_Rooms";
                        amount = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }



                    // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    SqlConnection conn;


                    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();


                    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as {0}) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0}
                                                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", amount);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }





                // creates a variable that combines the the directory of the new folder with the file name
                var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
                // This loop prevents duplicates. If a file is already in the folder, it will delete the file already in there and move this one in.
                // Shouldn't be an issue since each file will have a different name
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                }
                // moves it to the new folder
                csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);


            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents\Hotels", @"C:\Users\Documents\Completed Hotels");


        }
    }
}
```

EDITED to show what i tried doing with my Insert statement that didn't work:

```
var sqlCommand = string.Format("INSERT INTO HEWreport (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (@Property_ID,@val)", column);
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", amount);
```

The problem with this is that each amount value was on a different line. I want the 13 amount values that are on the same file to all be on the same line. I only want the values I get from another file to be on separate lines. In order to get the values on the same line for the one file I tested, I had to create a MERGE statement. Now that I want to implement more files, the MERGE isn't working, but neither does this because nothing is on the same line as each other. I just want it to read in a file, put everything from that one file on the same row but in separate columns and then put all of the data from the next file into its own row.

This is using insert:

```
13  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
14  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    37.31   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
15  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    97.23   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
16  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    102.42  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
17  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    41.75   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10694.25    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
19  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7681.26 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
20  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2828.94 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
21  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    184.05  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
22  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    201 NULL    NULL    NULL
23  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    79  NULL    NULL
24  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    75  NULL
25  TTNEW   5/27/2016   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This is using Merge:

```
12  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
```

This is my problem:

```
12  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
13  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
14  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
15  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
16  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
17  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
18  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
19  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
20  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
21  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
22  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
23  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
24  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
25  TTNEW   5/27/2016   39.3    37.31   97.23   102.42  41.75   10694.25    7681.26 2828.94 184.05  201 79  75  4
```

When i switch it back to merge, and give it 3 files to sort through, it takes the info from the first, and overwrites all existing data with it's data. However, I know the looping part works because when i use it as insert instead of a Merge, all of the data from all of the files are displayed, it just ends up being a lot of unnecessary rows.

Comment: Just to clarify, the data that I am reading in will have the same values for almost every column except FORMATTED_AMOUNT. I don't want it do update the rows every time the same property_id comes in. I want it to create a new row, each time it reads in a file, even if it is the same exact file

Comment: If you want to always insert a new row why are you using a MERGE statement. To always insert you would use an INSERT statement.

Comment: I think it didn't copy over correctly when I copy and pasted my code. Heading is defined correctly. I know that that is not the issue

Comment: @SeanLange the reason why I used a MERGE statement was because I was told it would be better since I am not just inserting specified numbers. record.RESORT changes with every file and amount changes multiple times with in each file. I wanted all of the amount values to all be in seperate columns in one row so I was told to use a MERGE

Comment: Do you understand what MERGE does? You stated that every single time you want a new row. Is that correct? If so, then using MERGE is the wrong statement because it will update an existing row that meets the MATCH criteria. This seems to contradict what you are stating you want to happen.

Comment: In my txt file, there are over 100 rows. I have the code that currently reads through and will pick out the exact 13 rows and select the one number i need from those rows and put them in a table. I want all 13 of those numbers to be in exactly one row in my table, with each of them having their own column. All of the txt files will select the same exact 13 rows and the numbers from those rows but the only thing that changes is the value of those numbers. I just want the data from one txt file to all be in one row and the data from the next txt file to be in the next row. How could i do that?

Comment: You should use an insert statement, not a merge.

Comment: How would I make that insert statement though? I don't know what numbers to insert because it changes every time depending on what row I get the number from and i don't know what rows to get the values from because that changes each time depending on the file. That's what the if statement is for, so I can find the rows. I know you keep saying to use an insert statement but I don't know how to implement it given the other parameters that I need to implement

Comment: Well I don't know what you are trying to do here. I can't see your table and have no idea what values you want or how you determine what values you need.

Comment: In the code i pasted, each time column = is set to something, that is a column in my table. In one file, Depending on what Heading and Group equal, the FORMATTED_AMOUNT value for that row, will go into that specific column. It will go through the whole file and it will encounter each one of those specified parameters once. It will take the FORMATTED_AMOUNT for just the row and then put it in that specified column. It will then find the FORMATTED_AMOUNT for the next row that meets the next parameters and put it in the next column. I want it to do that for a full txt file. This will take up one

Comment: row. i then want it to do the same for the next txt file, except put all of that information in the next row. So after two txt files I would have 15 columns with data filled out, but only two rows. Currently, I can't have more than one row

Comment: @SeanLange look at my edited post. I put my original Insert command and what was wrong with it and what i am trying to fix

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work?". I would like to help but you are not offering much in the way of information here.

Comment: I added my table. It looks a little off because of formatting when transferred over. So as you can see, this is the data from just one document. When i use the merge, it creates one row, with all of that on one line still in its respective column. When i use the insert, they are each on their own row, still in the column. This is the data for one file so i want it all in the same row. When i add another file i want that data on a new row

Comment: OK it has not been very clear what you are doing but I think I understand now. So your file has a row for each column of data and one of the columns will change indicating a new set of values. does that sound right? So yes, MERGE is correct. So back to the original question. I don't understand what the problem is that you are encountering.

Comment: The problem is that when i input a new file, instead of creating a new row with that information, it either overwrites the information already in the first row or just does nothing. I just want the next set of data from a different file to be put in the next row.

Comment: If you're still confused about the problem, i added the table that was made using the insert, and what happens to it after i switch back to merge. It just makes everything what the first file was.